# HighCharts Graph that Aggregates Values

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to create a **column graph** in Highcharts of the following nature:

X Axis: Time in seconds
Y Axis: how many times the particular time value appears.

In other words, I want to be able to have the following data series entered in:

**[50,50,30]**

and it should create a column chart with the following values:

**x: 30, y: 1
x: 50, y: 2**

Is this type of functionality possible in Highcharts?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try highcharts demo gallery http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ ? I bet it has all types of available charts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it's not directly related to highcharts.

You just have to create a javascript snippet before calling highcharts functions to spliut your data in the format you want and then use it in highcharts (series and totals/values). 
No charting  library will do that work for you.

the javascript snippet should look like this :

```
var options = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         defaultSeriesType: 'column'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Fruit Consumption'
     },
     xAxis: {
         categories: []
     },
     yAxis: {
         title: {
             text: 'Units'
         }
     },
     series: []
 };

var items = [50,30,50];
var series = {
             data: []
         };
var notfound;

items.sort();
 for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
   notfound= true;
   for(var j=0; j < options.xAxis.categories.length && notfound; j++) {       
     if (items[i] === options.xAxis.categories[j]) {
       notfound= false;
     }
   }
  if (notfound) {
     options.xAxis.categories.push(items[i]);
    series.data[j]= 1;
  } else {
    series.data[j]++;
  }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
 }
```

Something like this. I hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Hmm, I entered this code into the browser and it doesn't seem to compile (the chart is blank) :S

Comment: Hi, sorry but I didn't try it in an editor or live, I gave you the base idea and even more, write some code for it. You probably shouldn't have the array indexes for it to work so you should probably tweak a little bit the code

Comment: by the way, the code was based on : [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed)